# Getting the name of a chosen file in applescript

Tags: applescript

I need my AppleScript to know the name of a file chosen by a user in a `choose file` command. It sounds like it should be really simple, but I can't figure out the answer. The script extracts the frames from a gif file and puts the individual images in a folder inside the application's contents. It then changes the desktop background rapidly to the images inside the folder, hence giving you a gif for a wallpaper. However, I can't do this without knowing the name of the chosen gif file, as I don't know the names of the images in the folder. If there's some other easy way around this, that would be great too. This is what I have so far:

```
on delay duration
set endTime to (current date) + duration
repeat while (current date) is less than endTime
    tell AppleScript to delay duration
end repeat
end delay   
set gifFiles to choose file of type "com.compuserve.gif" with prompt "Select GIF"
set dest to quoted form of POSIX path of ((path to me as string) & "Contents:Resources:Gif")
set pScript to quoted form of "from AppKit import NSApplication, NSImage, NSImageCurrentFrame, NSGIFFileType; import sys, os
tName=os.path.basename(sys.argv[1])
dir=sys.argv[2]
app=NSApplication.sharedApplication() 
img=NSImage.alloc().initWithContentsOfFile_(sys.argv[1])
if img:
gifRep=img.representations()[0]
 frames=gifRep.valueForProperty_('NSImageFrameCount')
 if frames:
     for i in range(frames.intValue()):
         gifRep.setProperty_withValue_(NSImageCurrentFrame, i)
         gifRep.representationUsingType_properties_(NSGIFFileType, None).writeToFile_atomically_(dir + tName + ' ' + str(i + 1).zfill(2) + '.gif', True)
     print (i + 1)"
repeat with f in gifFiles
set numberOfExtractedGIFs to (do shell script "/usr/bin/python -c " & pScript & " " & (quoted form of POSIX path of f) & " " & dest) as integer
end repeat
repeat
set desktop_image to (path to me as string) & "Contents:Resources:Gif:"
tell application "Finder" to set the desktop picture to desktop_image
delay 0.05
set desktop_image to (path to me as string) & "Contents:Resources:Gif:"
tell application "Finder" to set the desktop picture to desktop_image
delay 0.05
set desktop_image to (path to me as string) & "Contents:Resources:Gif:"
tell application "Finder" to set the desktop picture to desktop_image
delay 0.05
set desktop_image to (path to me as string) & "Contents:Resources:Gif:"
tell application "Finder" to set the desktop picture to desktop_image
delay 0.05
set desktop_image to (path to me as string) & "Contents:Resources:Gif:"
tell application "Finder" to set the desktop picture to desktop_image
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the name with `System Events`

```
set gifFiles to choose file of type "com.compuserve.gif" with prompt "Select GIF"
tell application "System Events" to set gifFileName to name of gifFiles
```

or with the `info for` command, although it's deprecated since years it's still working even in El Capitan

```
set gifFiles to choose file of type "com.compuserve.gif" with prompt "Select GIF"
set gifFileName to name of (info for gifFiles)
```

Of course it's possible using the Finder but it's recommended to avoid involving the Finder as much as possible

Comment: That looks like it works, so thanks, but I've come across a new problem: set dest to quoted form of POSIX path of ((path to me as string) & "Contents:Resources:Gif") doesn't work. It doesn't give me an error message, it just simply doesn't do it. The closest I think I've come is: set dest to quoted form of POSIX path and (path to me) & "Contents:Resources:Gif". If you can figure out what's wrong with this, that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: You have to put the whole expression which is supposed to be quoted in parentheses : `set dest to quoted form of (POSIX path of (path to me) & "Contents/Resources/Gif")` and the literal path components must be separated by slash.

Answer (score 0):

To get file name, you must use the Finder name property :

```
set gifFiles to choose file of type "com.compuserve.gif" with prompt "Select GIF"
tell application "Finder" to set myName to name of file gifFiles
```

The variable myName contains the name of the selected file (with extension).